# Is there any way to change ttk Label Frame borderwidth?

Tags: tkinter, colors, label, frame, ttk

I'm trying to modify a ttk.Labelframe borderwidth so it is thicker, just as shown below.[image]

On the left the default thickness, on the right the thicker border i want.

I tried styles such as:

```
mystyle = ttk.Style()
mystyle.configure('MyStyle.TLabelframe.Label', font=('courier', 35, 'bold'))
mystyle.configure('MyStyle.TLabelframe.border', borderwidth = 10)
lblframe = ttk.Labelframe(root, text = "Label frame", style = 'MyStyle.TLabelframe')
```

But, the borderwidth keeps the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `borderwidth` option is under `TLabelframe` class instead of `TLabelframe.border`.  Also you need to change the `relief` option to `solid` to have the result in the image.

Note that not all themes support changing the border width, so try selecting other theme.

Below example works in my Windows 7:

```py
mystyle.theme_use('alt')   # choose other theme
mystyle.configure('MyStyle.TLabelframe', borderwidth=10, relief='solid', labelmargins=20)
mystyle.configure('MyStyle.TLabelframe.Label', font=('courier', 35, 'bold'))
```

[image]

Also note that `borderwidth` and `relief` can be set when creating the `Labelframe` widget as well:

```py
lblframe = ttk.Labelframe(root, text="Label frame", borderwidth=5, relief='solid', style='MyStyle.TLabelframe')
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked for me as well. Although, as you said, only for certain themes which is a bummer.